# Yii::app()->session not working

Tags: yii, yii1.x

I am trying to set session in yii 1.1 But we can not get any success. Could you please check below code:

**TestController**

```
function actionsetSession(){
      Yii::app()->session['returnUrl']='http://www.myurl.com';
      //some other code here
}

function actiongetSession(){
     echo Yii::app()->session['returnUrl']; exit;
     //Redirect URL
}
```

While hit my `getSession` after `setSession` only blank white page coming. Could you please help me.

Comment: How does your session component is configured?

Answer (score 3):

Try to debug your code with $_SESSION variable, if its working fine try this

```
For creating yii session

Yii::app()->session['userid'] = "value";

You can get value like this

$sleep = Yii::app()->session['userid'];
```

Also your action names should change to

```
actionSetSession
actionGetSession
```

Should you use the method 'open()' `Yii::app()->session->open();` depends on your configuration. If in the main.php, you have set the

`'session' => array (
    'autoStart' => true,
),`

then the Session will be started automatically by YII itself

Answer (score 0):

In yii 1, the session is handled by 'CHttpSession' class http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession

You should use the method 'open()' Yii::app()->session->open();
depends on your configuration. If in the main.php file, you have set the

```
'session' => array (
'autoStart' => true,
```

),

then the Session will be started automatically. You can refer the source code for the method 'init()' here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/web/CHttpSession.php#L83

Comment: `autoStart` is set to `true` by default.